# Trigonometry textbook or tutorial

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request

Is there an actual textbook or online resource that has a tutorial to solve $a\sin x+b\cos x=c$ for $a, b, c$ being either positive or negative?

I tried to find these types of equations/functions in some trigonometry textbooks in my library, but they didn't mention it
may be it is in a chapter that I don't know or it is presented with other words/title, I don't know.

Thanks

Comment: Trigonometry by S.L. Loney is a classic and contains a chapter on the solution of this equation. Should be in any library unless deemed to be ancient.

Comment: @Ishfaaq: Several freely available digital copies of Loney's trigonometry book can be found [here](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Sidney+Luxton+Loney%22). For mathos, there are other authors of similar (having many advanced topics) freely available texts, such as those by Isaac Todhunter, Ernest William Hobson, Clement Vavasor Durell and Alan Robson (co-authors), Elias Loomis, Émile Gelin, John Casey, Joseph Alfred Serret, etc.

Comment: all these you mention are books?

Answer (score 1):

Equations like this can be solved by turning them into quadratic equations. For example, you can write $x=2y$, so that
$$
\begin{align}
\sin x &= 2\sin y\cos y\\
\cos x &= \cos^2 y - \sin^2 y
\end{align}
$$
the equation can then be written as
$$
2a \sin y\cos y  + b(\cos^2 y - \sin^2 y) = c(\sin^2 y + \cos^2 y)
$$
Dividing by $\cos^2y$, we get
$$
(b+c)\tan^2 y - 2a\tan y + (c-b) = 0,\tag{1}
$$
which is an ordinary quadratic equation. Alternatively, you can square the original equation:
$$
a^2\sin^2 x + b^2\cos^2 x + 2ab\sin x\cos x = c^2(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)
$$
Dividing by $\cos^2x$, we get
$$
(a^2-c^2) \tan^2 x + 2ab\tan x + (b^2-c^2) = 0.\tag{2}
$$
Both procedures will work; the first method is better though, because equation (2) has 4 solutions, and only 2 of them will also be solutions of the original equation, so you have to check them.

Answer (score 1):

The usual method consists in writing that $a, b$ are the coordinates of a point in the plane, and use its polar coordinates, that is, $a=r\cos\theta$ and $b=r\sin\theta$. Then your equation becomes

$$r\cos\theta\sin x+r\sin\theta\cos x=c$$
$$\sin(\theta+ x)=\frac cr$$

If $\left|\frac cr\right|\leq 1$, then the solutions are

$$x=\arcsin\left(\frac cr\right)-\theta+2k\pi$$
and
$$x=\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac cr\right)+\theta+2k\pi$$

for $k\in\Bbb Z$.